# Weird subroutine interaction in perl while drawing pyramids out of stars

Tags: perl

I wasn't completely sure what to title this, but here is the issue. My goal is to create a subroutine called drawPyramids that will draw a pyramid out of *, with the number of rows depending on the command line parameter. With each row, the number of * increments by 2, so it goes 1-3-5-7 and so on. Here's what I have so far:

```
    sub drawRow { 
    my $space = $_[0];
    my $star = $_[1];
    for ($i=0;$i<$space;$i++) {
        print " ";
    }
    for ($i=0;$i<$star;$i++) {
        print "*";
    }
}

sub drawPyramid {
    my $rows = $_[0];
    my $x = 1;
    for ($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++) {
        drawRow($rows-$i,$x);
        print "\n";
        $x+=2;
    }


}
if(@ARGV == 0)  { #check if user entered parameter by checking size of array
    die "ERROR: Please supply command-line parameter\n";
}

foreach $a(@ARGV) { #check if number is negative
    if ($a < 0) {
      print "ERROR: Number must be non-negative\n";
    }
}

$sp = @ARGV[0];
$st = @ARGV[1];

drawPyramid($sp);
```

Lets say I run it as perl pyramid.pl 5 in my CMD. The expected result is:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

with 4 spaces before the first star on the first row, 3 spaces...and so on. However, this is what I get:

```
    *
   ***
 *****
```

The third row with 5 stars should have 2 spaces before the stars start, and the program doesn't even print the last two lines (which would have 7 and 9 stars).

What is wrong with the program? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When I read this question, I thought it involved Egyptian-style pyramids and astronomical stars! :)

Comment: Note that cases like this is why it is imperative to always `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both subroutines are reading and modifying the same global variable `$i` (also known as `$::i` or `$main::i`), so they're interfering with each other.

To fix this, you should instead use local variables, declared with `my`; that is, change this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= ...; $i++) {
```

to this:

```
for (my $i = 1; $i <= ...; $i++) {
```

throughout.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Or, preferably, you can use something more perlish like `for my $i (1..$rows)`